# Visual Studio 2019 not recognizing Jdk and Android SDK

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Visual Studio is showing in the Error List two Errors recently:

1. Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please click here to configure.
2. Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Java Development Kit (JDK). Please click here to configure.

Clicking the first one opens the Android Sdk Manager, which says "Sdk needs repair", but when clicking on "Repair" nothing happens. sdkmanager log says:

```
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] DEBUG: [monodroid] ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: ``, result=False
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] INFO: [monodroid] Looking for Android SDK...
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] DEBUG: [monodroid] ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=False
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] DEBUG: [monodroid] ValidateAndroidNdkLocation: ``, result=False
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] INFO: [monodroid] Looking for Android NDK...
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] INFO: [monodroid] Looking for Android SDK...
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] DEBUG: [monodroid] ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=False
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] DEBUG: [monodroid] ValidateJavaSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25`, result=True
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.6] ERROR: [monodroid] Error finding Android/Java SDKs
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not determine Android SDK location. Please provide `androidSdkPath`.
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkInfo..ctor(Action`2 logger, String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) in d:\a\1\s\external\androidtools\external\xamarin-android-tools\src\Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk\AndroidSdkInfo.cs:line 22
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidSdk.Refresh(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath)
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.7] INFO: Trying to get SDK path from Windows Registry
[2020-10-26 16:29:41.9] INFO: No Android SDK instance matching the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' path
```

Here is already one weird thing, because it says on ValidateJavaSdkLocation result=True, but when clicking the second error I get:

[image: Cannot find JDK files in specified path]

I reinstalled Visual Studio twice, the second time even running the InstallCleanup.exe with -f flag to clear out any junk left behind.

Both the android-sdk folder and the jdk microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25 exist and contain the usual files and folders. The only thing I can imagine is that visual studio / mono / whatever is looking for older versions of jdk and android sdk, but I have no idea why.

Other logs:

Ide.log contains:

```
[2020-10-26 16:28:57.9] ERROR: : Couldn't update deploy enabled state
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte 127.0.0.1:5037
```

which translates to "connection was refused on port 5037"

Versions:

```
VS 2019 Enterprise    16.7.6
Xamarin               16.7.000.456 (d16-7-6@f8d55b6)
Xamarin.Android SDK   11.0.2.0 (d16-7/025fde9)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 83105ba
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-7@1f3388a
    ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-7@017078f
```

Comment: `clicking on "Repair" nothing happens`, it just without any response? Maybe you need to wait a while. Did you try to repair the visual-studio in the visual-studio installer?

Comment: I tried removing all the components in the sdk manager. Then repair gives me a screen to install them again. But when that is done, it still shows the "sdk is broken" message, but clicking on repair does not do anything. I didnt try repair in the installer, but I did uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Try to repair in the installer and if the problem still exist, report a problem to [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) inside visual-studio.

Comment: So ive been trying out things and monodroid finally spilled what is wrong:
`MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\common7\ide\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0`
Its using v1 of mono instead of the newest v11 in that directory. Any idea where I can set which version it should use? is that in some kind of registry entry?

Comment: Maybe re-install the Xamarin.Android nuget package?

Comment: So my office computer blue-screened and now it just works. I have no idea what happened. Thanks all of you for your suggestions!

Comment: I was able to fix the issue following this answer - https://superuser.com/a/1663493

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see those settings? Make sure you check the Xamarin.Android settings:

[image: screenshot of Xamarin.Android settings]

Can you please check what the contents of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` are? Is it empty, maybe it contains a partial installation of the Android SDK?

There should be a `build-tools`, `platforms`, `platform-tools` and `tools` folder in there as minimum.

Do you have the Environment Variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` defined? What about `JAVA_SDK`?

Comment: In the Xamarin.Android settings it has those exact paths. Only with red crosses next to them. And the Folders contain all those subfolders you mentioned. It might be that the Android SDK is partially installed because the AndroidSdkManager keeps asking to repair, but the repairing does nothing. As you can see in the first log it is looking in the right places to validate Android and Java Sdk, just not happy with it.